# How to make hyperlinked tabs with specific colors?

Tags: tikz-pgf, hyperref, color, foreach, book-design

How can one make side tabs linked to specific locations inside a document (eg.: beginning of each chapter) ?

Comment: Welcome on TeX.sx! Note that you can achieve code blocks by indenting every line of code by 4 white spaces, or simply selecting it and clicking the "code" `{}` button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible answer:

```
\documentclass[]{book}

\usepackage[vmargin=3cm,hmargin=3cm,lmargin=3cm,rmargin=3cm,hoffset=0mm,voffset=0mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,pageanchor=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}  
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{totcount}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\def\TabThickness{8mm}

% RIGHT SIDE TABS

% Right side tabs dimensions
\def\RightTabsNumberOf{8}
\newlength\RightTabVerticalLength  
\setlength\RightTabVerticalLength{\dimexpr\paperheight/\RightTabsNumberOf\relax} 
\newlength\RightTabThickness
\setlength\RightTabThickness{\TabThickness}

% Right side tabs positioning
\newlength\xRightTab  
\setlength\xRightTab{\dimexpr\paperwidth-(\RightTabThickness)+1pt\relax}
\newlength\xRightTabText   
\setlength\xRightTabText{\dimexpr\RightTabThickness/2+1pt\relax}

\newlength\yRightTabOne
\newlength\yRightTabTwo
\newlength\yRightTabThree
\newlength\yRightTabFour
\newlength\yRightTabFive
\newlength\yRightTabSix
\newlength\yRightTabSeven
\newlength\yRightTabEight

\setlength\yRightTabOne{\dimexpr\paperheight-(\RightTabVerticalLength*1/2)\relax}
\setlength\yRightTabTwo{\dimexpr\paperheight-(\RightTabVerticalLength*3/2)\relax}
\setlength\yRightTabThree{\dimexpr\paperheight-(\RightTabVerticalLength*5/2)\relax}
\setlength\yRightTabFour{\dimexpr\paperheight-(\RightTabVerticalLength*7/2)\relax}
\setlength\yRightTabFive{\dimexpr\paperheight-(\RightTabVerticalLength*9/2)\relax}
\setlength\yRightTabSix{\dimexpr\paperheight-(\RightTabVerticalLength*11/2)\relax}
\setlength\yRightTabSeven{\dimexpr\paperheight-(\RightTabVerticalLength*13/2)\relax}
\setlength\yRightTabEight{\dimexpr\paperheight-(\RightTabVerticalLength*15/2)\relax}

% Right side tabs style
\tikzset{RightTabStyle/.style={align=center,
text=red!80!black,font=\scshape\bfseries,
text width=\RightTabVerticalLength,
text height=\RightTabThickness, 
text depth=\xRightTabText,
inner sep=0pt,thick,rectangle,rounded corners=5pt,rotate=270,
draw=blue,fill=yellow!80}}  %


\newcommand{\TheRightSideTabs}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]  
    \coordinate (CoordinatesRightTabOne) at (\xRightTab,\yRightTabOne) ;
    \coordinate (CoordinatesRightTabTwo) at (\xRightTab,\yRightTabTwo) ; 
    \coordinate (CoordinatesRightTabThree) at (\xRightTab,\yRightTabThree) ; 
    \coordinate (CoordinatesRightTabFour) at (\xRightTab,\yRightTabFour) ; 
    \coordinate (CoordinatesRightTabFive) at (\xRightTab,\yRightTabFive) ; 
    \coordinate (CoordinatesRightTabSix) at (\xRightTab,\yRightTabSix) ; 
    \coordinate (CoordinatesRightTabSeven) at (\xRightTab,\yRightTabSeven) ; 
    \coordinate (CoordinatesRightTabEight) at (\xRightTab,\yRightTabEight) ; 

\node (NodeRightTabOne)   at (CoordinatesRightTabOne) {\hyperlink{LinkToChapterOne}{\tikz\node[RightTabStyle]{Chapter 1};}}; 

\node (NodeRightTabTwo)   at (CoordinatesRightTabTwo) {\hyperlink{LinkToChapterTwo}{\tikz\node[RightTabStyle]{Chapter 2};}}; 

\node (NodeRightTabThree)   at (CoordinatesRightTabThree) {\hyperlink{LinkToChapterThree}{\tikz\node[RightTabStyle]{Chapter 3};}}; 

\node (NodeRightTabFour)   at (CoordinatesRightTabFour) {\hyperlink{LinkToChapterFour}{\tikz\node[RightTabStyle,text=green!80!black,fill=red!20!white]{Chapter 4};}}; 

\node (NodeRightTabFive)   at (CoordinatesRightTabFive) {\hyperlink{LinkToChapterFive}{\tikz\node[RightTabStyle]{Chapter 5};}}; 

\node (NodeRightTabSix)   at (CoordinatesRightTabSix) {\hyperlink{LinkToChapterSix}{\tikz\node[RightTabStyle]{Chapter 6};}}; 

\node (NodeRightTabSeven)   at (CoordinatesRightTabSeven) {\hyperlink{LinkToChapterSeven}{\tikz\node[RightTabStyle]{Chapter 7};}}; 

\node (NodeRightTabEight)   at (CoordinatesRightTabEight) {\hyperlink{LinkToChapterEight}{\tikz\node[RightTabStyle]{Chapter 8};}}; 

\end{tikzpicture}
}    


% LEFT SIDE TABS

% Left side tabs dimensions
\def\LeftTabsNumberOf{2}
\newlength\LeftTabVerticalLength  
\setlength\LeftTabVerticalLength{\dimexpr\paperheight/\LeftTabsNumberOf\relax} 
\newlength\LeftTabThickness
\setlength\LeftTabThickness{\TabThickness}


% Left side tabs positioning
\newlength\xLeftTab  
\setlength\xLeftTab{\dimexpr(\LeftTabThickness)\relax}
\newlength\xLeftTabText   
\setlength\xLeftTabText{\dimexpr(\LeftTabThickness*1/2)\relax}

\newlength\yLeftTabOne
\newlength\yLeftTabTwo
\setlength\yLeftTabOne{\dimexpr\paperheight-(\LeftTabVerticalLength*1/2)\relax}
\setlength\yLeftTabTwo{\dimexpr\paperheight-(\LeftTabVerticalLength*3/2)\relax}


% Left side tabs style
\tikzset{LeftTabStyle/.style={align=center,
text=pink!80!black,font=\scshape\bfseries,
text width=\LeftTabVerticalLength,
text height=\xLeftTab, 
text depth=\xLeftTabText,
inner sep=0pt,thick,rectangle,rounded corners=5pt,rotate=90,
draw=red,fill=blue!5}}  %


\newcommand{\TheLeftSideTabs}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]  
    \coordinate (CoordinatesLeftTabOne) at (\xLeftTab,\yLeftTabOne) ;
    \coordinate (CoordinatesLeftTabTwo) at (\xLeftTab,\yLeftTabTwo) ; 

\node (NodeLeftTabOne)   at (CoordinatesLeftTabOne) {\hyperlink{LinkToChapterOne}{\tikz\node[LeftTabStyle]{Chapter 1};}}; 

\node (NodeLeftTabTwo)   at (CoordinatesLeftTabTwo) {\hyperlink{LinkToChapterTwo}{\tikz\node[LeftTabStyle]{Chapter 2};}}; 

\end{tikzpicture}
}    


% UP SIDE TABS

% Up side tabs dimensions
\def\UpTabsNumberOf{2}
\newlength\UpTabThickness
\setlength\UpTabThickness{\TabThickness}
\newlength\UpTabLength
\setlength\UpTabLength{\dimexpr((\paperwidth-5cm)/\UpTabsNumberOf)\relax}

% Up side tabs positioning
\newlength\xUpTabOne
\setlength\xUpTabOne{\dimexpr(\UpTabLength*1/2+2.5cm)\relax}
\newlength\xUpTabTwo  
\setlength\xUpTabTwo{\dimexpr(\UpTabLength*3/2+2.5cm)\relax}

\newlength\yUpTab
\setlength\yUpTab{\dimexpr((\paperheight-\UpTabThickness)*2)\relax}
\newlength\yUpTabText
\setlength\yUpTabText{\dimexpr(\UpTabThickness*1/2)\relax}

% Up side tabs style
\tikzset{UpTabStyle/.style={align=center,
text=blue!80!black,font=\scshape\bfseries,
text width=\UpTabLength,
text height=\yUpTab, 
text depth=\yUpTabText,
inner sep=0pt,thick,rectangle,rounded corners=5pt,rotate=0,
draw=orange!80!black,fill=orange!5}}  %


\newcommand{\TheUpSideTabs}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]  
    \coordinate (CoordinatesUpTabOne) at (\xUpTabOne,\yUpTab) ;
    \coordinate (CoordinatesUpTabTwo) at (\xUpTabTwo,\yUpTab) ; 

\node (NodeUpTabOne)   at (CoordinatesUpTabOne) {\hyperlink{LinkToChapterOne}{\tikz\node[UpTabStyle]{Chapter 1};}}; 

\node (NodeUpTabTwo)   at (CoordinatesUpTabTwo) {\hyperlink{LinkToChapterTwo}{\tikz\node[UpTabStyle]{Chapter 2};}}; 

\end{tikzpicture}
}    



% DOWN SIDE TABS

% Down side tabs dimensions
\def\DownTabsNumberOf{2}
\newlength\DownTabThickness
\setlength\DownTabThickness{\TabThickness}
\newlength\DownTabLength
\setlength\DownTabLength{\dimexpr((\paperwidth-5cm)/\DownTabsNumberOf)\relax}

% Down side tabs positioning
\newlength\xDownTabOne
\setlength\xDownTabOne{\dimexpr(\UpTabLength*1/2+2.5cm)\relax}
\newlength\xDownTabTwo  
\setlength\xDownTabTwo{\dimexpr(\UpTabLength*3/2+2.5cm)\relax}

\newlength\yDownTab
\setlength\yDownTab{\dimexpr(\DownTabThickness)\relax}
\newlength\yDownTabText
\setlength\yDownTabText{\dimexpr(\DownTabThickness*1/2)\relax}

% Down side tabs style
\tikzset{DownTabStyle/.style={align=center,
text=pink!80!black,font=\scshape\bfseries,
text width=\DownTabLength,
text height=\yDownTab, 
text depth=\yDownTabText,
inner sep=0pt,thick,rectangle,rounded corners=5pt,rotate=0,
draw=green!80!black,fill=green!5}}  %


\newcommand{\TheDownSideTabs}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]  
    \coordinate (CoordinatesDownTabOne) at (\xDownTabOne,\yDownTab) ;
    \coordinate (CoordinatesDownTabTwo) at (\xUpTabTwo,\yDownTab) ; 

\node (NodeDownTabOne)   at (CoordinatesDownTabOne) {\hyperlink{LinkToChapterOne}{\tikz\node[DownTabStyle]{Chapter 1};}}; 

\node (NodeDownTabTwo)   at (CoordinatesDownTabTwo) {\hyperlink{LinkToChapterTwo}{\tikz\node[DownTabStyle]{Chapter 2};}}; 

\end{tikzpicture}
}    


\AddToShipoutPicture{
\TheRightSideTabs
\TheLeftSideTabs
\TheUpSideTabs
\TheDownSideTabs
}

\begin{document}
\mainmatter


\cleardoublepage
\hypertarget{LinkToChapterOne}{\chapter{Chapter One}}
\lipsum

\cleardoublepage
\hypertarget{LinkToChapterTwo}{\chapter{Chapter Two}}
\lipsum

\cleardoublepage
\hypertarget{LinkToChapterThree}{\chapter{Chapter Three}}
\lipsum

\cleardoublepage
\hypertarget{LinkToChapterFour}{\chapter{Chapter Four}}
\lipsum

\cleardoublepage
\hypertarget{LinkToChapterFive}{\chapter{Chapter Five}}
\lipsum

\cleardoublepage
\hypertarget{LinkToChapterSix}{\chapter{Chapter Six}}
\lipsum

\cleardoublepage
\hypertarget{LinkToChapterSeven}{\chapter{Chapter Seven}}
\lipsum

\cleardoublepage
\hypertarget{LinkToChapterEight}{\chapter{Chapter Eight}}
\lipsum


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With the package TColorBox.

Vertical tabs on the right side if odd page, on the left side if even page.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[]{hyperref}
\usepackage[all]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{lipsum}


% Tabs dimensions
\def\RightTabsNumberOf{5}
\newlength\RightTabVerticalLength  
\setlength\RightTabVerticalLength{\dimexpr(\paperheight/\RightTabsNumberOf*97/100)\relax} 
\newlength\RightTabVerticalDistance  
\setlength\RightTabVerticalDistance{\dimexpr(\paperheight/\RightTabsNumberOf-(1mm/\RightTabsNumberOf))\relax} 



\tcbset{enhanced,size=normal,center upper,fontupper={\Large\bfseries},arc=3mm,width=\RightTabVerticalLength}

\newcommand{\LeftRightClickableTcolorBox}[2]{
 \begin{tcolorbox}[colback={#2!50},
 if odd page={rounded corners=north}{rounded corners=south},
 if odd page={sharp corners=south}{sharp corners=north},
 if odd page={bottomrule=0mm}{toprule=0mm},
 hyperref=#1
]
\nameref{#1}
\end{tcolorbox}
}


\newcommand{\UpClickableTcolorBox}[2]{
 \begin{tcolorbox}[colback={#2!50},rounded corners=south,
 sharp corners=north,toprule=0mm,
 hyperref=#1
]
\nameref{#1}
\end{tcolorbox}
}

\newcommand{\DownClickableTcolorBox}[2]{
 \begin{tcolorbox}[colback={#2!50},
 sharp corners=south, rounded corners=north, bottomrule=0mm,
 hyperref=#1
]
\nameref{#1}
\end{tcolorbox}
}

\newcommand{\RightTabs}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
\node (RightTab1) [above left,xshift=1mm,rotate=90] at 
(current page.north east){
\LeftRightClickableTcolorBox{LinkToChapterOne}{violet}};
\node (RightTab2) [above left,xshift=1mm,
yshift=-\RightTabVerticalDistance,rotate=90] at 
(current page.north east){
\LeftRightClickableTcolorBox{LinkToChapterTwo}{blue}};
\node (RightTab3) [above left,xshift=1mm,
yshift=-2*\RightTabVerticalDistance,rotate=90] at
(current page.north east){
\LeftRightClickableTcolorBox{LinkToChapterThree}{green}};
\node (RightTab4) [above left,xshift=1mm,
yshift=-3*\RightTabVerticalDistance,rotate=90] at 
(current page.north east){
\LeftRightClickableTcolorBox{LinkToChapterFour}{yellow}};
\node (RightTab5) [above left,xshift=1mm,
yshift=-4*\RightTabVerticalDistance,rotate=90] at 
(current page.north east){
\LeftRightClickableTcolorBox{LinkToChapterFive}{red}};
\end{tikzpicture}
}



\newcommand{\LeftTabs}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
\node (LeftTab1) [below left,xshift=-1mm,rotate=90] at 
(current page.north west){
\LeftRightClickableTcolorBox{LinkToChapterOne}{violet}};
\node (LeftTab2) [below left,xshift=-1mm,
yshift=-\RightTabVerticalDistance,rotate=90] at 
(current page.north west){
\LeftRightClickableTcolorBox{LinkToChapterTwo}{blue}};
\node (LeftTab3) [below left,xshift=-1mm,
yshift=-2*\RightTabVerticalDistance,rotate=90] at
(current page.north west){
\LeftRightClickableTcolorBox{LinkToChapterThree}{green}};
\node (LeftTab4) [below left,xshift=-1mm,
yshift=-3*\RightTabVerticalDistance,rotate=90] at 
(current page.north west){
\LeftRightClickableTcolorBox{LinkToChapterFour}{yellow}};
\node (LeftTab5) [below left,xshift=-1mm,
yshift=-4*\RightTabVerticalDistance,rotate=90] at 
(current page.north west){
\LeftRightClickableTcolorBox{LinkToChapterFive}{red}};
\end{tikzpicture}
}



\newcommand{\UpTabs}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
\node (UpTab1) [below,xshift=-0.5*\RightTabVerticalDistance,yshift=0mm,rotate=0] at (current page.north){
\UpClickableTcolorBox{LinkToChapterOne}{orange}};
\node (UpTab2) [below,xshift=0.5*\RightTabVerticalDistance,yshift=0mm,rotate=0] at 
(current page.north){
\UpClickableTcolorBox{LinkToChapterTwo}{pink}};
 \end{tikzpicture}
}


\newcommand{\DownTabs}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
\node (DownTab1) [above,xshift=-\RightTabVerticalDistance,yshift=0mm,rotate=0] at (current page.south){
\DownClickableTcolorBox{LinkToChapterOne}{cyan}};
\node (DownTab2) [above,xshift=0mm,yshift=0mm,rotate=0] at 
(current page.south){
\DownClickableTcolorBox{LinkToChapterTwo}{magenta}};
\node (DownTab3) [above,xshift=\RightTabVerticalDistance,
yshift=0mm,rotate=0] at
(current page.south){
\DownClickableTcolorBox{LinkToChapterThree}{teal}};
 \end{tikzpicture}
}


\strictpagecheck
\AddToShipoutPicture{
\UpTabs
\DownTabs
\checkoddpage
\ifoddpage
\RightTabs
\else
\LeftTabs
\fi
}


\begin{document}

\cleardoublepage
\chapter{Chapter One\label{LinkToChapterOne}}
\lipsum

\cleardoublepage
\chapter{Chapter Two\label{LinkToChapterTwo}}
\lipsum

\cleardoublepage
\chapter{Chapter Three\label{LinkToChapterThree}}
\lipsum

\cleardoublepage
\chapter{Chapter Four\label{LinkToChapterFour}}
\lipsum

\cleardoublepage
\chapter{Chapter Five\label{LinkToChapterFive}}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Package minted Error: You must invoke LaTeX with the -shell-escape flag. \RequirePackage{minted}[2011/09/17] !!