# clickable chapters on even and odd pages

Tags: pdftex

Following the great idea of Gonzalo Medina presented in [Clickable Chapters on the right side of each page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/181081/clickable-chapters-on-the-right-side-of-each-page), I wanted to extend this also for two sided books. What I am doing wrong? It seems that this code doesn't care if the page is even or odd...

Here is the code:

```
      \documentclass[11pt,BCOR8mm,final,linktocpage,twoside,headsepline,a4paper]{scrbook}
     \usepackage{background}
     \usepackage{etoolbox}
     \usepackage{graphicx}
     \usepackage{totcount}
     \usepackage{lipsum}
     \usepackage{truncate}
     \usepackage{changepage}
     \usepackage{ifthen}
     \usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
     \usepackage{scrextend}
     \usepackage{ifoddpage}
     \strictpagecheck


     \def\striptext to#1 #2{\def\striptextout{}\def\tmp{#1}\striptextA #2\relax\end}
     \def\striptextA{\futurelet\next\striptextB}
     \def\striptextB{\ifx\next\relax \expandafter \skiptoend
        \else \ifx\next\spacetoken
                  \edef\striptextoutA{\striptextout\space}%
                  \def\next{\afterassignment\striptextD \let\next= }%
              \else \def\next{\striptextC}%
        \fi   \fi
        \next
     }
     \def\striptextC#1{\edef\striptextoutA{\striptextout#1}\striptextD}
     \def\striptextD{\setbox0=\hbox{\striptextoutA}%
        \ifdim\wd0>\tmp\relax \expandafter \skiptoend
        \else \let\striptextout=\striptextoutA \expandafter \striptextA
        \fi
     }
     \def\skiptoend#1\end{}
     \edef\tmp{\let\noexpand\spacetoken= \space}\tmp




     % to have access to the total number of sections
     \regtotcounter{chapter}

     % every section starts on a new page
     \pretocmd{\chapter}{\clearpage}{}{}


     % auxiliary lengths for the height of the frame and the width of each tab
     \newlength\mylen
     \newlength\mylena

     % style for the section tabs
     \tikzset{
     tab/.style={
       text width=\mylena,
       draw=gray,
       thick,
       rectangle,
       rounded corners=2pt,  % 12pt
       align=center,
       text width=23pt,   
       inner sep=0pt,
       fill=gray!20,
       font=\sffamily\scriptsize
       }
     }
     % style for the current section tab
     \tikzset{selectedtab/.style={tab,color=white,fill=gray!90}}

     % the page number is showed in the background material
     \pagestyle{empty}

     % the main part; as background material we place the border, 
     % the section (current and other) tabs and the page number 
     \AtBeginDocument{
     % calculation of the width for each tab
     \setlength\mylen{\dimexpr\textheight+2cm\relax}
     \ifnum\totvalue{chapter}>0
     \setlength\mylena{\dimexpr\mylen/\totvalue{chapter}\relax}
     \fi
     \checkoddpage\ifoddpage%
     \backgroundsetup{
     scale=1,
     color=black,
     angle=0,
     opacity=1,
     contents= {
       \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
       \node[
         inner sep=0pt,
         text width=\the\dimexpr\textwidth+1.5cm\relax
       ] 
         at (current page.center) (border) {\rule{0pt}{\dimexpr\textheight+2cm\relax}};
       \foreach \valchapter in {0,...,\numexpr\totvalue{chapter}-1\relax}
       {
         \node[
           \ifnum\thechapter<\numexpr\valchapter+1\relax 
             tab%
           \else 
           \ifnum\thechapter>\numexpr\valchapter+1\relax 
             tab%
           \else selectedtab%
           \fi\fi,
           minimum height=\mylena
           ] 
           at ([yshift=-(0.5+\valchapter)*\mylena]border.north east) 
           (tab-\valchapter) 
           {\hspace*{10pt}\rotatebox{+90}{%
            \hyperlink{sec:\valchapter}{{  \scriptext   {\nameref{sec:\the\numexpr\valchapter }}  \striptextout \ldots   }\relax}%
             }
           };
       }
       \node[
         draw=gray,
         line width=2pt,
         rectangle,
         rounded corners=10pt,
         inner sep=0pt,
         text width=\the\dimexpr\textwidth+1.5cm\relax,
         fill=white
       ] 
         at (current page.center) 
         {\rule{0pt}{\dimexpr\textheight+2cm\relax}};
       \node[font=\small\sffamily,fill=white]   % 
         at (border.south) 
         {\makebox[3em][c]{\thepage}};
     \end{tikzpicture}}
       }
     %}
     \else
     \egroup
     \backgroundsetup{
     scale=1,
     color=black,
     angle=0,
     opacity=1,
     contents= {
       \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
       \node[
         inner sep=0pt,
         text width=\the\dimexpr\textwidth+1.5cm\relax
       ] 
         at ([xshift=-20.3cm] current page.center) (border) {\rule{0pt}{\dimexpr\textheight+2cm\relax}};
       \foreach \valchapter in {0,...,\numexpr\totvalue{chapter}-1\relax}
       {
         \node[
           \ifnum\thechapter<\numexpr\valchapter+1\relax 
             tab%
           \else 
           \ifnum\thechapter>\numexpr\valchapter+1\relax 
             tab%
           \else selectedtab%
           \fi\fi,
           minimum height=\mylena
           ] 
           at ([yshift=-(0.5+\valchapter)*\mylena]border.north east) 
           (tab-\valchapter) 
           {\hspace*{0pt}\rotatebox{-90}{%
            \hyperlink{sec:\valchapter}{{  \scriptext  {\nameref{sec:\the\numexpr\valchapter }}  \striptextout \ldots   }\relax}%  
             }
           };
       }
       \node[
         draw=gray,
         line width=2pt,
         rectangle,
         rounded corners=10pt,
         inner sep=0pt,
         text width=\the\dimexpr\textwidth+1.5cm\relax,
         fill=white
       ] 
         at (current page.center) 
         {\rule{0pt}{\dimexpr\textheight+2cm\relax}};
       \node[font=\small\sffamily,fill=white]   % 
         at (border.south) 
         {\makebox[3em][c]{\thepage}};
     \end{tikzpicture}}
       }
     \fi}
     %%%%%






     \begin{document}

     \chapter{Introduction}
     \label{sec:0}
     \hypertarget{sec:0}{}
     \lipsum[1-3]
     \chapter{Idea No 1}
     \label{sec:1}
     \hypertarget{sec:1}{}
     \lipsum[1-3]
     \chapter{Idea No 2}
     \label{sec:2}
     \hypertarget{sec:2}{}
     \lipsum[1-3]
     \chapter{Idea No 3}
     \label{sec:3}
     \hypertarget{sec:3}{}
     \lipsum[1-3]
     \chapter{Idea No 4}
     \label{sec:4}
     \hypertarget{sec:4}{}
     \lipsum[1-3]
     \chapter{TIdea No 5}
     \label{sec:5}
     \hypertarget{sec:5}{}
     \lipsum[1-3]

     \end{document}
```

Comment: Your example code produces an error with `\scriptext`. Could you please fix this? Anyway. Do you want the positions of the tabs to be always in the outer margin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The background package documentation gives an example (Example 4) on how to proceed when different backgrounds are desired for odd and even pages; basically, you need the `\AddEverypageHook` hook and to use `\BgMaterial` at the end.

Here's a reduced version of your code (your `\scriptext` and `\striptextout`commands were producing errors, so I suppressed them):

```
\documentclass[11pt,BCOR8mm,final,linktocpage,twoside,headsepline,a4paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage[contents={}]{background}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{totcount}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{truncate}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{ifoddpage}
\strictpagecheck

\regtotcounter{chapter}

\pretocmd{\chapter}{\clearpage}{}{}

\newlength\mylen
\newlength\mylena

\tikzset{
tab/.style={
  text width=\mylena,
  draw=gray,
  thick,
  rectangle,
  rounded corners=2pt,  % 12pt
  align=center,
  text width=23pt,   
  inner sep=0pt,
  fill=gray!20,
  font=\sffamily\scriptsize
  }
}
\tikzset{selectedtab/.style={tab,color=white,fill=gray!90}}

\pagestyle{empty}

\AtBeginDocument{
  \setlength\mylen{\dimexpr\textheight+2cm\relax}
  \ifnum\totvalue{chapter}>0
    \setlength\mylena{\dimexpr\mylen/\totvalue{chapter}\relax}
  \fi
  \AddEverypageHook{
    \ifodd\value{page}%
      \backgroundsetup{
        scale=1,
        color=black,
        angle=0,
        opacity=1,
        contents={%
       \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
       \node[
         inner sep=0pt,
         text width=\the\dimexpr\textwidth+1.5cm\relax
       ] 
         at (current page.center) (border) {\rule{0pt}{\dimexpr\textheight+2cm\relax}};
\foreach \valchapter in {0,...,\numexpr\totvalue{chapter}-1\relax}
       {
         \node[
           \ifnum\thechapter<\numexpr\valchapter+1\relax 
             tab%
           \else 
           \ifnum\thechapter>\numexpr\valchapter+1\relax 
             tab%
           \else selectedtab%
           \fi\fi,
           minimum height=\mylena
           ] 
           at ([yshift=-(0.5+\valchapter)*\mylena]border.north east) 
           (tab-\valchapter) 
           {\hspace*{10pt}\rotatebox{+90}{%
            \hyperlink{sec:\valchapter}{{ {\nameref{sec:\the\numexpr\valchapter }}   \ldots   }\relax}%
             }
           };
       }         
\node[
         draw=gray,
         line width=2pt,
         rectangle,
         rounded corners=10pt,
         inner sep=0pt,
         text width=\the\dimexpr\textwidth+1.5cm\relax,
         fill=white
       ] 
         at (current page.center) 
         {\rule{0pt}{\dimexpr\textheight+2cm\relax}};
       \node[font=\small\sffamily,fill=white]   % 
         at (border.south) 
         {\makebox[3em][c]{\thepage}};
         \end{tikzpicture}%        
        }
      }
    \else
      \backgroundsetup{
        scale=1,
        color=black,
        angle=0,
        opacity=1,
        contents= {%
       \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
       \node[
         inner sep=0pt,
         text width=\the\dimexpr\textwidth+1.5cm\relax
       ] 
         at (current page.center) (border) {\rule{0pt}{\dimexpr\textheight+2cm\relax}};
\foreach \valchapter in {0,...,\numexpr\totvalue{chapter}-1\relax}
       {
         \node[
           \ifnum\thechapter<\numexpr\valchapter+1\relax 
             tab%
           \else 
           \ifnum\thechapter>\numexpr\valchapter+1\relax 
             tab%
           \else selectedtab%
           \fi\fi,
           minimum height=\mylena
           ] 
           at ([yshift=-(0.5+\valchapter)*\mylena]border.north west) 
           (tab-\valchapter) 
           {\hspace*{-10pt}\rotatebox{+90}{%
            \hyperlink{sec:\valchapter}{{ {\nameref{sec:\the\numexpr\valchapter }}   \ldots   }\relax}%
             }
           };
       }         
\node[
         draw=gray,
         line width=2pt,
         rectangle,
         rounded corners=10pt,
         inner sep=0pt,
         text width=\the\dimexpr\textwidth+1.5cm\relax,
         fill=white
       ] 
         at (current page.center) 
         {\rule{0pt}{\dimexpr\textheight+2cm\relax}};
       \node[font=\small\sffamily,fill=white]   % 
         at (border.south) 
         {\makebox[3em][c]{\thepage}};
         \end{tikzpicture}%        
        }
      }
    \fi\BgMaterial
  }
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}
\label{sec:0}
\hypertarget{sec:0}{}
\lipsum[1-3]
\chapter{Idea No 1}
\label{sec:1}
\hypertarget{sec:1}{}
\lipsum[1-3]
\chapter{Idea No 2}
\label{sec:2}
\hypertarget{sec:2}{}
\lipsum[1-3]
\chapter{Idea No 3}
\label{sec:3}
\hypertarget{sec:3}{}
\lipsum[1-3]
\chapter{Idea No 4}
\label{sec:4}
\hypertarget{sec:4}{}
\lipsum[1-3]
\chapter{TIdea No 5}
\label{sec:5}
\hypertarget{sec:5}{}
\lipsum[1-3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Remark

At shipout time the page number is known, so there's no need to `\checkoddpage...` and a simple `\ifodd` test is perfectly safe.

Comment: @Medina: sorry for the delay of my answer, caused by some field campaigns (geophysical mappings). But thanks a lot, your idea will be again of great help. I will work on it tomorrow. Too tired now...