# Supressing page style for one page doesn't work

Tags: pdftex

Using Gonzalo Medina's [code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/181081/clickable-chapters-on-the-right-side-of-each-page) and trying to include one A3-page, I cannot suppress the page style using \thispagestyle{empty} or cleardoublepage=plain. Please give me a hint.

The code:

```
\documentclass[DIV=calc,pagesize]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[a5paper,vmargin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor}
\usepackage{totcount}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{afterpage}

% to have access to the total number of sections
\regtotcounter{section}

% every section starts on a new page
\pretocmd{\section}{\clearpage}{}{}

% auxiliary lengths for the height of the frame and the width of each tab
\newlength\mylen
\newlength\mylena

% style for the section tabs
\tikzset{
tab/.style={
  text width=\mylena,
  draw=gray,
  thick,
  rectangle,
  rounded corners=12pt,
  align=center,
  text width=53pt,
  inner sep=0pt,
  fill=gray!20,
  font=\sffamily\LARGE
  }
}
% style for the current section tab
\tikzset{selectedtab/.style={tab,color=white,fill=gray!90}}

% the page number is showed in the background material
\pagestyle{empty}

\AtBeginDocument{
% calculation of the width for each tab
\setlength\mylen{\dimexpr\textheight+2cm\relax}
\ifnum\totvalue{section}>0
\setlength\mylena{\dimexpr\mylen/\totvalue{section}\relax}
\fi

% the main part; as background material we place the border, 
% the section (current and other) tabs and the page number 
\backgroundsetup{
scale=1,
color=black,
angle=0,
opacity=1,
contents= {
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \node[
    inner sep=0pt,
    text width=\the\dimexpr\textwidth+1.5cm\relax
  ] 
    at (current page.center) (border) {\rule{0pt}        {\dimexpr\textheight+2cm\relax}};
  \foreach \valsection in {0,...,\numexpr\totvalue{section}-1\relax}
  {
    \node[
      \ifnum\thesection<\numexpr\valsection+1\relax 
    tab%
  \else 
  \ifnum\thesection>\numexpr\valsection+1\relax 
    tab%
  \else selectedtab%
  \fi\fi,
  minimum height=\mylena
  ] 
  at ([yshift=-(0.5+\valsection)*\mylena]border.north east) 
  (tab-\valsection) 
  {\hspace*{25pt}\rotatebox{-90}{%
    \hyperlink{sec:\valsection}{Section \the\numexpr\valsection+1\relax}%
    }
  };
  }
      \node[
    draw=gray,
    line width=2pt,
    rectangle,
    rounded corners=10pt,
    inner sep=0pt,
    text width=\the\dimexpr\textwidth+1.5cm\relax,
    fill=white
  ] 
    at (current page.center) 
    {\rule{0pt}{\dimexpr\textheight+2cm\relax}};
  \node[font=\LARGE\sffamily,fill=white] 
    at (border.south) 
    {\makebox[3em][c]{\thepage}};
\end{tikzpicture}}
  }
}

\begin{document}

\section{Section One}
\hypertarget{sec:0}{}
\lipsum[1-3]
\section{Test Section Two}
\hypertarget{sec:1}{}
\lipsum[1-2]


\clearpage
\afterpage{% 
\KOMAoptions{paper=a3,paper=landscape}%,cleardoublepage=plain}
\recalctypearea
%\thispagestyle{empty}
\areaset{\dimexpr \textwidth+.5\paperwidth}{\textheight}
\noindent\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\rule{\textwidth}{\dimexpr\textheight-3\baselineskip\relax}
\captionof{figure}{Some notes...}
\end{minipage}

\clearpage
\KOMAoptions{paper=a4,paper=portrait}
\areaset{\dimexpr \textwidth-\paperwidth}{\textheight}
\recalctypearea\clearpage

}



\section{Test Section Three}
\hypertarget{sec:2}{}
\lipsum[1-2]
\section{Test Section Four}
\hypertarget{sec:3}{}
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

And the result is:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not use a pagestyle for the border. Therefore `\thispagestyle{empty}` does not suppress the border.

You could load package `scrlayer` and define a layer pagestyle. With class `scrreprt` I would do this for chapters.

```
\documentclass[DIV=calc,pagesize]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[a5paper,vmargin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}% loads also xcolor and graphicx
\usepackage{totcount}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{hyperref}

% to have access to the total number of sections
\regtotcounter{chapter}

% auxiliary length for the width of each tab
\newlength\mylena

\tikzset{
  tab/.style={% style for the section tabs
    text width=\mylena,
    draw=gray,
    thick,
    rectangle,
    rounded corners=12pt,
    align=center,
    text width=53pt,
    inner sep=0pt,
    fill=gray!20,
    font=\sffamily\LARGE,
    overlay
  },
  selectedtab/.style={% style for the current section tab
    tab,
    color=gray!90,
    text=white
  },
  pagenumber/.style={% style for the page number
    font=\LARGE\sffamily,
    fill=white,
    text width=3em,
    align=center
  }
}

\usepackage{scrlayer}
\DeclarePageStyleByLayers{border}{border.odd}
\pagestyle{border}
\renewcommand\chapterpagestyle{border}

\DeclareNewLayer[
  background,
  oddpage,
  textarea,
  addvoffset=-1cm,
  addhoffset=-.75cm,
  addheight=2cm,
  addwidth=1.5cm,
  contents={%
  \ifnum\totvalue{chapter}>0
    \setlength\mylena{\dimexpr\layerheight/\totvalue{chapter}\relax}%
  \fi
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \pgfdeclarelayer{background}
      \pgfsetlayers{background,main}
      \node[
        draw=gray,
        fill=white,
        inner sep=0pt,
        minimum width=\layerwidth-\pgflinewidth,
        minimum height=\layerheight-\pgflinewidth,
        rounded corners=10pt,
        line width=2pt
      ](border){};
      \node[pagenumber]at (border.south){\thepage};
      \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
        \foreach \valchapter in {0,...,\numexpr\totvalue{chapter}-1\relax}{%
          \node[
            \ifnum\value{chapter}<\numexpr\valchapter+1\relax 
              tab%
            \else 
              \ifnum\value{chapter}>\numexpr\valchapter+1\relax 
                tab%
              \else
                selectedtab%
              \fi
            \fi,
            minimum height=\mylena-\pgflinewidth
          ] at ([yshift=-(0.5+\valchapter)*\mylena]border.north east)
          {\hspace*{25pt}\rotatebox{-90}{%
              \hyperlink{chap:\valchapter}{\chaptername\ \the\numexpr\valchapter+1\relax}%
            }
          };
        }
      \end{pgfonlayer}
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  }
]{border.odd}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Chapter One}
\hypertarget{chap:0}{}
\lipsum[1-3]
\chapter{Test Chapter Two}
\hypertarget{chap:1}{}
\lipsum[1-2]

\clearpage
\afterpage{% 
  \KOMAoptions{paper=a3,paper=landscape,DIV=10}
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \noindent\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \rule{\textwidth}{\dimexpr\textheight-3\baselineskip\relax}
    \captionof{figure}{Some notes \ldots}
  \end{minipage}
  \clearpage
}

\chapter{Test Chapter Three}
\hypertarget{chap:2}{}
\lipsum[1-2]
\chapter{Test Chapter Four}
\hypertarget{chap:3}{}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that I have changed the code inside the argument of `\afterpage`.

If you remove the `\thispagestyle{empty}` for the A3 page you would get:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your "MWE" is not very minimal, and also not working, as it generates error messages.

But to get rid of the background on the A3 page you have to add

```
\NoBgThispage
```

on that page as the `background` documentation says.